# How to use query result in a parametric manner within the other queries in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm gonna use output of queries in LINQ as the input of the other...
Here is the definition of the database handler:

```
DataClassDataContext DB = new DataClassDataContext();
```

And here is the succession of the queries and utilization of their results.

```
var axleIDQuery = (from Axles in DB.Axles
    where Axles.Name == axleComboBox.Text
    select Axles.AxleID).singleOrDefault();

var checkpointIDQuery = from Checkpoints in DB.Checkpoints
                    where Checkpoints.AxleID == AxleIDQuery
                    select new{ Checkpoints.checkpointID };

var AVLQuery = from AVLs in DB.AVLs
                    where AVLs.checkpointID == checkpointIDQuery.toString();
                    select new{ 
                                AVL.Vehicle,
                                AVL.MCT,
                                AVL.CheckpointID
                              };
```

The rest is the try to present the result:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = AVLQuery.toLost();
```

The problem is that nothing will be shown in the datagridview.
Anybody can enlighten me about the wrong part, please?!

PS. Debug shows that the problem is with third query. Because the result of the middle one can be shown in datagridview, deservedly.

Comment: I don't think linq has a `when` keyword, do you mean `where`? Also no `ToLost()` method, do you mean `ToList()`

Comment: @BenRobinson: Sorry...Edited! I just typed that in a simple editor

Comment: checkpointIDQuery defined twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkpointIDQuery` is a query result, when evaluate it will be collection, but you simply do `ToString` for it.
So when where check condition it always false

for quick fix you can change your query like this with [join clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)

```
var AVLQuery = from AVLs in DB.AVLs
               join cId in checkpointIDQuery on  AVLs.checkpointID equals cId.checkpointID 
               select new{ 
                          AVL.Vehicle,
                          AVL.MCT,
                          AVL.CheckpointID
                         };
```

**UPDATE:** if you want remove `singleOrDefault` then you need change your query like this

```
var axleIDQuery = from Axles in DB.Axles
                  where Axles.Name == axleComboBox.Text
                  select Axles.AxleID;

var checkpointIDQuery = from Checkpoints in DB.Checkpoints
                        join axelId in axleIDQuery on Checkpoints.AxleID equals axelId 
                        select new{ Checkpoints.checkpointID };
```

Comment: Thank you!... I had the similar problem with the utilization of the first query result into the second query; i.e. if the singleOrDefault() is removed, I will have an error from the second query due to the type incompatibility. Would you please guiding me that how should I handle the case upon the second query, if I am eager to remove that singleOrDefault() method?!

Comment: I'm appreciated because of your help :)